# Нет перевода справки о закрытой бете

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка, нет-в-transifex

На страницах [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) появилась статья [How to Ask Questions in Private Beta](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta), не имеющая перевода.

> [image: кхе-кхе]

Строки бы вроде есть в transifex, но почему-то не используются. Может быть какое-то не точное совпадение.

Судя по всему, данная статья вообще не должна фигурировать в справке сайта, вышедшего из состояния закрытой беты. Соответствующий баг репорт на MSE: [“How to Ask Questions in Private Beta” is listed in every site’s help centre](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290401/339911)

Comment: Наверное у нас не должно быть этой ссылки, мы давно прошли закрытую бету.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, это намёк со стороны модераторов StackExchange.

Comment: @Arhad back to school?

Comment: @alexolut let`s go back to school, to the oldscool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Текст [переведён](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4894/176217) и может быть использован для переноса в раздел справки сайта. Если вы заметите какие-то проблемы перевода, не стесняйтесь исправлять их. Менеджер сообщества планирует в [ближайшее время](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=35917850#35917850) осуществить перенос текста на сайт.