# Редактирование страницы справки «How to Ask Questions in Private Beta»

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Ссылка на страницу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta

Заголовок: «How to Ask Questions in Private Beta»

---

Welcome to the private beta for $SiteName

The tone and quality of the questions asked during this temporary private beta are critically important.

If the private beta doesn't produce enough *high quality expert level questions*, it won’t proceed onward to the public beta. To help ensure your site makes it out of private beta, here are some tips:

### Avoid “easy” questions

It’s tempting to start with easy, superficial questions: surveys, polls, and rudimentary questions like “what are some good books on this topic” or “what are the best blogs on this topic”. Those are not good questions for the private beta – they don’t reflect the actual content that we want this site to contain, and are not representative of it.

### Think like an expert

Stick to actual, real, objective questions with concrete answers that a working professional or expert in this field might encounter as a part of their actual, real, job. Stock the site with a bunch of on-topic, expert questions and answers, so that when the site opens to the public, it’s already pre-populated with a bunch of the kind of content that will attract *other* experts.

### You get the site you build

The first questions set the tone and topic of a site for a long time. Those early questions say a lot about what your community could become. And questions asked during the private beta will be on the front page when potential experts see your site for the first time. So please **make those first questions exemplary ones that are interesting, challenging, and worthy of imitation**.

*The text above was adapted from [Asking the First Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/).*

#### Related

- [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)
- [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)
- [Are Some Questions Too Simple?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/)

discuss on meta »

Comment: Почему-то ссылка `discuss on meta »` не подхватилась.

Comment: @alexolut Потому что там специальная переменная, которая действует только для страниц справки.

Comment: Может её надо было оставить как есть в тексте? А ... всё, вижу :)

Comment: @alexolut Ага, так и есть. Ее следует оставить так, как она представлена сейчас. Движок автоматически преобразует переменную в правильную ссылку во время загрузки.

Comment: Вопрос, описывающий [дефект](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4659/176217).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заголовок: «Как задавать вопросы во время закрытой беты»

---

Добро пожаловать на закрытую бету сайта $SiteName

Характер и качество вопросов, задаваемых в процессе временной закрытой беты, критически важны.

Если закрытая бета не позволяет добиться *высококачественных экспертных ответов*, она не сможет перейти к этапу открытой беты. Чтобы помочь сайту выйти из этапа закрытой беты, воспользуйтесь следующими советами:

### Избегайте «простых» вопросов

Заманчиво начинать с простых, поверхностных вопросов: обзоры, опросы и элементарные вопросы такие как «какие есть хорошие книги по этой теме» или «какие блоги лучшие по этой теме». Такие вопросы не достаточно хороши для закрытой беты — они не отражают реальное содержимое, которое мы желаем видеть на этом сайте, и они не показательны для него.

### Думайте как эксперт

Придерживайтесь актуальных, реальных, объективных вопросов с точными ответами, с которыми работающие профессионалы или эксперты в этой области могут столкнуться как с частью их актуальной, реальной работы. Наполняйте сайт множеством экспертных, соответствующих тематике, вопросов и ответов так, чтобы после открытия сайта для широкой публики, он уже был достаточно заполнен содержимым, привлекательным для *других* экспертов.

### Вы сами строите сайт

Первые вопросы задают тон и тему сайта на долгое время. Эти ранние вопросы много говорят о том, чем может стать ваше сообщество. Вопросы, задаванные во время закрытой беты, будут на главной странице, когда потенциальные эксперты увидят ваш сайт в первый раз. Поэтому, пожалуйста, **сделайте эти первые вопросы образцовыми, интересными, увлекательными и достойными подражания**.

*Текст выше является упрощённой версией статьи [«Как задавать первые вопросы»](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/).*

#### Связанные статьи

- [«Хороший субъективный, плохой субъективный»](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)
- [«Настоящие вопросы имеют ответы»](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)
- [«Некоторые вопросы слишком простые?»](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/)

обсудить на Мете »

Comment: Кстати, а обсуждается альтернатива? Заголовок: "Этап закрытой беты в SO на русском успешно пройден. Дата" и ниже, например, список ссылок на другие ресурсы справки и не только.

Comment: @vp_arth эти дополнения, я думаю, сможет сделать уже CM, если сочтет нужным. К переводу они не относятся. По сути, это будет лишь подсказка о наличии бага с отображением данной страницы справки на сайте, уже прошедшем упомянутый этап.

Comment: Я к тому, что нам необязательно её вообще переводить. Это же просто шаблон. Мы можем написать там, что-то более полезное, чем потерявшие актуальность рекомендации.

Comment: @vp_arth для сайтов, вышедших из закрытой беты, ссылки на статью вообще быть не должно в справке. Перевод может быть полезен для других (потенциальных) русскоязычных сайтов Stack Exchange, если они когда-то появятся. В качестве заглушки бага для ruSO можно безусловно предложить альтернативный текст.